# Como hacer que la barra de desplazamiento se oculte, pero vuelva a aparecer cuando se le coloca el cursor encima

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

Quiero hacer una barra de desplazamiento como la que tiene chicksgold.com, pero lo único que logro es cambiar su tamaño y color, como puedo hacer para que se coloque encima del contenido, desaparezca y reaparezca cuando se le coloca el cursor sobre ella.
Este es el código que estoy utilizando

```
.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    autoHide: "scroll"
}
.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #b9a5bd;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #ac94ac;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Ese sitio no hace eso, lo que hace es crear un scroll desde cero usando `divs` y programando una serie de eventos para mostrarlo o ocultarlo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKI2i.png